# How to handle go back in a 404 page caused by a crash. React-Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Lets put on the following scenario.

Im using my React Website, something crashes, and a 404 page is rendered.
This webpage contains a "go back button" , which should take the user back to navigation. Problem is, it cant take him back to the previous page, because the previous page created the 404 page, so it would be stuck in an infinite loop.

My approach has been keeping track of 2 urls before the website crashes. The one where the website works, and the one where the website crashed.

url1: page works
url2: page website crashed

I do something like this

```
 if (localStorage.getItem("url1") == undefined && localStorage.getItem("url2") == undefined) {
      localStorage.setItem("url1", props.history.location.pathname);
      localStorage.setItem("url2", props.history.location.pathname);
    }

    if (localStorage.getItem("url1") != localStorage.getItem("url2") && localStorage.getItem("url1") != undefined && localStorage.getItem("url2") != undefined) {
      let url2: any = localStorage.getItem("url2")?.toString();
      localStorage.setItem("url1", url2);
      localStorage.setItem("url2", props.history.location.pathname);
    }

    if (localStorage.getItem("url1") == localStorage.getItem("url2") && localStorage.getItem("url1") != undefined && localStorage.getItem("url2") != undefined) {
      localStorage.setItem("url2", props.history.location.pathname);
    }
```

That way, whenever a website is redirected to 404. I simply use the following code in the button that is supposed to take the user back to the page that DID work.

```
pushBackError = () => {
    const { history } = this.props;
    this.setState({hasError: false})
    let url : any = localStorage.getItem("url1")?.toString();
    history.push(url)
  }
```

This way I can recover from the error just fine. So whats the issue there?

I have a navigation Header, which has a goBack button, and is available in every single page (Except the error ones).
Implying that if I have the  following flow

> page1 (contains a history.goBack button)-> page2 (crashes) ->
> errorpage (I click Back button and it returns to page1 using
> pushBackError()) -> page1 (i click the back button which triggers
> history.goBack) -> returns me to the errorPage since the history stack
> is filled.

How could I avoid this? The ideal flow would be

> page1 -> page2 (crashes) -> errorPage -> page1 (i click go back) ->
> goes to the page that was previous to page1 as if the navigation that
> caused the page2 crash never happened.